# Validar registros duplicados (SQL SEREVER)

Tags: sql-server

Muy buen día a todos, espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda en sql server,
tengo una tabla llamada ListaPrecios con los siguientes campos Id_Lista, Id_Cliente, Id_Producto, PrecioA, PrecioB la cual esta relacionada con mi tabla Cliente y Producto.

Al momento de agregar una nueva lista seleccionó el cliente y el producto y también les asigno los precios, la cuestión es que debo de poder registrar varias listas con el mismo cliente  pero con diferente producto, si agrego una nueva lista con el mismo cliente y un producto ya asignado debe de hacer la validación que ese producto ya esta asignado a ese cliente.

De la misma manera con las demás listas,espero me puedan ayudar con la consulta de antemano les agradezco mucho.

Comment: Hola! Comparte algo de lo que has hecho para que podamos ayudarte mejor!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda ya lo resolví.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso del `exists` . `EXISTS(o NOT EXISTS)` está especialmente diseñado para verificar si algo existe y, por lo tanto, debería ser (y es) la mejor opción. Se detendrá en la primera fila que coincida. Deberías hacer algo así:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ListaPrecios WHERE Id_Producto = @Id_Producto and Id_Cliente= @Id_Cliente)
    BEGIN
    -- Aquí ejecutas el código en el caso de que exista.
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    -- Aquí ejecutas el código opcional en el caso de que NO exista.
    END
```

**Aclaración:** `@Id_Cliente` y `@Id_Producto` son los parámetros que le debes pasar.

Para aprender mas de este operador [click aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp)

Espero que te ayude. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas Gracias probare este método.

Comment: Ya lo resolví de esta manera en verdad muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegra ayudar! recuerda marcar la respuesta como solución en el caso que lo sea, para que otros usuarios la puedan ver mas rápido. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo agregando un constraint en la tabla. Pero si ya tienes registros en tu tabla, primero deberás asegurarte que no tienes duplicados, y en caso de tenerlos eliminarlos.

```
 ALTER TABLE ListaPrecios 
 ADD CONSTRAINT clave_unica_ListaPrecios UNIQUE(Id_Cliente, Id_Producto)
```

Solo te recuerdo, que si ya hay registros en tu tabla, y existe alguno duplicado, no podrás ejecutar el ALTER TABLE. Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda..